# formArray getting error in ng drag drop angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ngdraggable

Team

I am creating drag and drop for moving fields from my toolbar to panel

But I am  getting error while dragging and drop in the form Here is the error which i am getting currently.

[image]

Here is my ts code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.fields = localStorage.getItem('fields') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fields')) : {}
this.getFieldData();
this.getCountryData();
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  arr: this.formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])
})
this.personalDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  guardianName: ['', Validators.required],
  guardianContactNo: ['', Validators.required],
  dob: ['', Validators.required],
  universityName: [''],
  middleName: ['']
});
this.contactDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
  address1: ['', Validators.required],
  address2: ['', Validators.required],
  apt: ['', Validators.required],
  countryData: ['', Validators.required],
  stateData: ['', Validators.required],
  cityData: ['', Validators.required],
  postalCode: [''],
  phoneNumberH: [''],
  phoneNumberO: [''],
  phoneNumberOff: [''],
  mobileNumber: [''],
  email: ['']
});
```

}

```
  onAnyDrop(e: any, formGroupName: string) {
console.log(e, formGroupName);
if (formGroupName === 'personalDetails') {
  this.addInput(this.personalDetails, e.fieldType, 'ABCED', false);
} else if (formGroupName === 'contactDetails') {
  this.addInput(this.contactDetails, e.fieldType, 'XYZABC', false);
}
```

}

```
addInput(fg, type: string, label: string, required: boolean = false): void {
const arrayControl = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['formArray'];
let newGroup
switch (type) {
  case 'Text': {
    fg.array([{
      [label]: ['', required ? Validators.required : null]
    }])
    break;
  }
  case 'Number': {
    fg.array({
      [label]: [0, required ? Validators.required : null]
    });
    break;
  }
  default: {
    fg.array({
      [label]: ['', required ? Validators.required : null]
    });
    break;
  }
}
arrayControl.push(newGroup);
```

}

Here is my HTML

```
     <div class="fieldexplorer">
          <div class="sectionHeader_field">
                Field Explorer
          </div>
          <div draggable [dragData]="label" *ngFor="let label of labels;">
              <div class="hoverselect" style="padding: 8px;border: 1px solid black;">
                   <span [ngClass]="(label.fieldType=='Number'?'numberbefore':(label.fieldType=='List'?'listbefore':'radiobefore'))">
                   </span> {{label.labelName}}
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

This is my Dropable area

```
<div class="row" [droppable] [dragHintClass]="'drag-hint'" (onDrop)="onAnyDrop($event, 'personalDetails')">
</div>
<div class="row" [droppable] [dragHintClass]="'drag-hint'" (onDrop)="onAnyDrop($event, 'contactDetails')">
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `onAnyDrop`.

Comment: @N.F. I added onAnyDrop code also please check

Comment: What are you trying to do in `addInput`? Are you trying to add a new FormControl named `label` into `this.personalDetails` or `this.contactDetails` and add it to `this.myForm.arr`?

Comment: @N.F. you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `addInput` as below.

```
addInput(fg, type: string, label: string, required: boolean = false): void {
  let newControl: FormControl;
  switch (type) {
    case 'Text': {
      newControl = new FormControl('');
      break;
    }
    case 'Number': {
      newControl = new FormControl(0);
      break;
    }
    default: {
      newControl = new FormControl('');
      break;
    }
  }
  if (required) {
    newControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
  }
  fg.addControl(label, newControl);
  const arrayControl = this.myForm.get('arr') as FormArray;  
  arrayControl.push(fg);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer just want to understand why you have removed this part 

[label]: ['', required ? Validators.required : null]

Comment: The part is common for all `type`. They will be done after `switch`.

Comment: thank you so much that error is not coming 

i have one more query here i am trying to drag and rop the fields drag is working prefectly fine but drop is not working as expected i am using ng-drag-drop

Comment: will you be available in chat for some time please i will explain more there

Comment: It is another issue. I suggest you to post a new question.

Comment: I am not sure how to post that in detail here that's what i thought have a seperate chat discussion

Comment: here is the seperate question for that

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898936/drag-and-drop-dynamic-fields-using-ng-drag-drop-using-angular-not-working-as-exp

please help me out here

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have knowledge on ng-drag-drop. You should be patient anyone who knows it will help you or resolve your issue on your own.